# White device toolbar

Tags: google-chrome, responsive-design, opera, darkmode

I have a problem with the display of the mobile test tool for opera and chrome. I don't know why, but my appearance has changed so that I only have a light theme instead of a dark one. I have had this on chrome for some time, and it has appeared at the opera today.

Neither plugin breaks it because I uninstalled each one and this problem keeps popping up, and I don't want to reinstall my entire browser for this reason.

Have any of you encountered such a problem?

Screen: https://i.stack.imgur.com/66oBu.jpg and https://i.stack.imgur.com/GwuYl.jpg

Comment: In case you're on Linux and can live with a slightly older Chrome / Chromium: You can install the last version that didn't have this problem with the following command: `flatpak update --commit=0e8ba1c6b91bc816b3232e485d9b588c671013bba73bc6fce8815ba26e0da115 org.chromium.Chromium`

Comment: I ran into this bug today this week as well!